# PayPal Web Service. CreateAndSendInvoice

Tags: web-services, wsdl, paypal

I need to create and send an invoice from an internal web app to a customer for an outstanding amount for an order that has changed.

Use Case:
Customer orders on our website and pays using express checkout
Our staff need to modify the order and charge the difference using a internal CRM web app

2 questions:

1. Is this the right API to use for this purpose? CreateAndSendInvoice
   https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/invoicing/CreateAndSendInvoice_API_Operation/
2. Can I use the PayPal web service to make the call? PayPal Web Service
   http://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl

Answer (score 0):

That's a classic API. You'll want to consult the [Getting started with Classic Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/). It tells you the proper endpoints.

You would probably need to use the Invoicing system to get additional funds from Express Checkout users because you can't run a new charge at will like you can with a credit card.

Comment: Is it possible to use the WSDL service to request money from customers?

Comment: My thought was to use CreateAndSendInvoice found here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/

Comment: You mean the SOAP API? Yes, you can. SOAP and NVP are considered Classic.

Comment: I added the WSDL to my project but I don't see a call to "CreateAndSendInvoice" in the web service. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's the method of the call, not how you would call it in SOAP. I never used SOAP, however, so I'm not sure I can help you there.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to call CreateAndSendInvoice using the Web Service. The WSDL does not seem to have a definition for that API call. I was just wondering if you can use the WSDL to make that call?

Comment: I think I just what I'm looking for. There is another web service here: https://svcs.paypal.com/Invoice?wsdl